# How can I link PayPal PDT transaction to specific order?

Tags: php, paypal

I see many examples of how to display transaction information to a user with PDT. I cannot find a way to associate a Paypal payment with a specified ID so that when the transaction is completed, I can update that ID in the database as paid.

How am I supposed to get an ID that I specify back from Paypal so I know what the payment is for? I cannot use the email address or name or anything else. It must be an ID that I specify.

I see some people using item_number, but I am using a Paypal encrypted button so I cannot add on form variables to post to Paypal when the user clicks the pay now button.

I see this on websites all the time, so I know there must be some way to do this. I just can't find it anywhere...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most often people encrypt their own buttons and use either the custom field which gets sent pack to you, or the item number field. Look into how to encrypt your own buttons with PHP.

PayPal offers a sample in their SDK which can be found [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#paypalpaymentsstandard).

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize I could encrypt my own buttons. Then, I can add in my own item number or custom field and still have an encrypted button... I am going to read through this, it seems like it is just what I need. Thanks very much!

Comment: @user1560676 Your welcome, if the answer is what you were looking for, consider accepting it by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this excellent piece that succinctly lays out how to make dynamic encrypted paypal buttons. It is just what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php